# Handle mutliple write operations to the same signal in vhdl

Tags: signals, vhdl

I have n components that compute a certain hash and I don't know when they will be done. When they are done, they should send their found hash to a master component, where it doesn't matter which of the hashes reaches the master first, as long as he receives one.

Is there a way of implementing this that avoids race conditions in the case where 2 or more components finish computing their hash at the exact same time without needing n signals (one for each hash) coming into the master?

I tried to implement the following that would lay between the master and the n components, but realized that this does not make much sense as there is still a race condition with all components writing to the same hash_in signal.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- System to connect multiple components to one master
-- When a component finds a hash, it writes to hash_in. Bus saves hash_in to an internal signal
-- and waits until master_ready is set to 1 to pass it the next signal
-- (Master sets master_ready to 0 while it's processing the last hash).

entity connector is
  port(
    -- The signal that all n components write to
    hash_in             : in    std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
    -- Signal indicating if master is ready for the next hash
    master_ready        : in    std_logic;
    -- Hash we give to master
    hash_out            : out   std_logic_vector(255 downto 0)
  );
end connector;

architecture arch of connector is

  signal hash_internal : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

  hash_out <= hash_internal;

  process(master_ready, hash_in)
  begin

    if(master_ready) then
      hash_internal <= hash_in;
    end if;

  end process;

end architecture;
```

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Having multiple devices writing to the same signal will create multiple drivers on the same signal. You need a mux that can select the appropriate component based on the decode of all the ready signals. Priority can be applied in the decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you must minimize the size of the resulting design.

VHDL is (only) a way to describe a hardware design.  So before you write any VHDL, you should determine how the function can be implemented with the minimal size in the target technology.

It is unlikely that the target technology supports signals with multiple drivers, so this means that you can't write the design in VHDL where you try to use such a feature, since the synthesis tool will be unable to map the VHDL design to the target technology.

It may be that the smallest possible design is by using a mux that can select the appropriate component based on the decode of all the ready signals, as Tricky writes in the comment.

It may seam like a rather large solution, but if that is the best the target technology allows, then it is the minimal solution.

So button line: Understand what the target technology allows, write the VHDL so the design is efficiently mapped by the synthesis tool to the target technology, and finally check that resulting implementation is as expected.